# permissions sharepoint 2007 and infopath

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using sharepoint 2007 and infopath 2007. I have created a form which is located under document library which you can access from site actions -> veiw all content.

As a sharepoint admin I can view a page by going to site actions -> clicking view all content which has an option of clicking into a directory and then come to page that has a 'new' button(tab) to bring up a form to be filed out.

but my ordinary read/write permission users cant see the directory once they click in the veiw all content so that they can get the form from the 'new' tab and fill it out.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the users must have the contribute permission to the list where the form is located. so that they can see and fill the form.